# (using processing library in Eclipse) how do I use window mode?

Tags: java, processing

http://processing.org/learning/eclipse/ according step 5, I used  `PApplet.main( new String[] { "--present", "MyGame" });` in my Main method. The game is in full screen mode, how do I switch to window mode? 
(I don't want to just run it as Java Applet...)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use window mode, simply don't pass the argument:

```
PApplet.main(new String[] {"MyGame"});
```

If you want to switch from present mode to window mode, you'll need to handle things manually AFAIK. PApplet extends java's [Applet](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html) class and uses a [Frame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html) to add contents into. 
Here's a quick hack:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;


public class MyGame extends PApplet {

    public void setup(){
        size(400,400);
        background(255);
        smooth();
        stroke(0,32);
    }
    public void draw(){
        fill(255,1);
        rect(0,0,width,height);
        translate(width/2,height/2);
        rotate(frameCount * .1f);
        line(0,0,width/3,0);
    }
    public void keyPressed(){
        if(key == 'f') exitFullscreen();
    }

    private void exitFullscreen() {
        frame.setBounds(0,0,width,height);
        setBounds((screenWidth - width) / 2,(screenHeight - height) / 2,width, height);
        frame.setLocation((screenWidth - width) / 2,(screenHeight - height) / 2);
        setLocation((screenWidth - width) / 2,(screenHeight - height) / 2);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PApplet.main(new String[] { "--present", "MyGame" });
    }
}
```

Feel free tinker with the exitFullscreen() method to get the desired setup.

Comment: How would you do it the other way round, i.e., switching from windowed to fullscreen mode?

Comment: @Koffiman You can try something like: `java.awt.Rectangle fs = new java.awt.Rectangle(0,0,displayWidth,displayHeight);
    frame.setBounds(fs);
    setBounds(fs);` but the issue you can't get the frame to be undecorated (no border/close button/etc.). Perhaps you should post this as a separate question and get more answers/suggestions

Comment: Done! Could you perhaps post your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260640/java-processing-2-0-using-eclipse-switching-from-window-to-fullscreen-and-ba) to get the discussion going?